# Setuptools setup.py installing when dependencies not satisfied

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I have a `setup.py` that looks a bit (okay, exactly) like this:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup
import subprocess
import distutils.command.build_py

class BuildWithMake(distutils.command.build_py.build_py):
    """
    Build using make.
    Then do the default build logic.

    """
    def run(self):
        # Call make.
        subprocess.check_call(["make"])

        # Keep installing the Python stuff
        distutils.command.build_py.build_py.run(self)


setup(name="jobTree",
    version="1.0",
    description="Pipeline management software for clusters.",
    author="Benedict Paten",
    author_email="benedict@soe.ucsc.edu",
    url="http://hgwdev.cse.ucsc.edu/~benedict/code/jobTree.html",
    packages=["jobTree", "jobTree.src", "jobTree.test", "jobTree.batchSystems",
    "jobTree.scriptTree"],
    package_dir= {"": ".."},
    install_requires=["sonLib"],
    # Hook the build command to also build with make
    cmdclass={"build_py": BuildWithMake},
    # Install all the executable scripts somewhere on the PATH
    scripts=["bin/jobTreeKill", "bin/jobTreeStatus", 
    "bin/scriptTreeTest_Sort.py", "bin/jobTreeRun", 
    "bin/jobTreeTest_Dependencies.py", "bin/scriptTreeTest_Wrapper.py", 
    "bin/jobTreeStats", "bin/multijob", "bin/scriptTreeTest_Wrapper2.py"])
```

It installs the package perfectly fine when run with `./setup.py install`. However, it does this whether or not the "sonLib" package is installed, ignoring the dependency.

Is this expected behavior? Should a `setup.py install` blithely proceed if the dependencies are not installed, leaving it up to pip or whatever to install them beforehand? If not, and `setup.py install` ought to fail when dependencies are absent, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Some version information:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jan 19 2012, 21:40:50) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import setuptools
>>> setuptools.__version__
'0.6c12'
>>>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `setuptools` doesn't actually check dependencies. You might want to look into using [distribute](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/) instead.

Comment: @murgatroid99d - distribute and setuptools have been merged back together. and setuptools usually _does_ install dependencies.

Comment: Run `pip install setuptools -U` to get the 0.9 version, I think this one accepts the `install_requires` option as distribute does.

Answer (score 0):

The [default `install` command for Distutils `setup`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/commandref.html#installing-modules-the-install-command-family) doesn't know anything about dependencies. If you are running that, you're right that dependencies will not be checked.

Just going by what you've show in the `setup.py`, though, you are using Setuptools for the `setup` function. The [Setuptools `install` command](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#install-run-easy-install-or-old-style-installation) is declared to run `easy_install`, which in turn does check and download dependencies.

It is possible you are explicitly invoking the Distutils `install`, by specifying `install --single-version-externally-managed`.